# How to share product details from IOS app in Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdksharekit

I am making a online shopping based App. I want to create a functionality to post my product details in Facebook. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

I want to share product details automatically in fb when the user press share button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you already have your product image and the detail information about it. So Facebook provides an SKD where you can share your product information from just one click of button. And also u can make users to redirect to your link when the users click on your post.

for more information about FBSDKShareKit please go through this
[FB for developers link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)

Here is the code for sharing your product info and sending users to your page when they click on it,

just write this code in your method of share button.

```
 FBSDKShareLinkContent *content =[[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your product page URL here"];
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your product image url here"];
content.contentTitle= @"Title of your product";
content.contentDescription=@"Description of your product";
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog=[[FBSDKShareDialog alloc]init];
dialog.mode=FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
if (![dialog canShow]) {
    // fallback presentation when there is no FB app
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb;
    //
}
dialog.shareContent=content;
dialog.delegate=self;
dialog.fromViewController=self;
[dialog show];
```

make sure you import FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h and FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h in your .h file and add the delegates to it.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS 11 Update**

The `Facebook`, `Twitter`, and Other apps options have been removed in the `Settings` app.

That apps will now be treated like other apps, using the iOS `sharing extensions`

```
let share = [image, text, url]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: share, applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can also use third party `SDK` for individual sharing

[Facebook Sharing Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social)

[Twitter Sharing Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhwGm.png)

==========================================================================

You can sharing post using [Social Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social). you can also sharing on twitter.

[image]

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
#import <Social/Social.h>


if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];        
}
```

**SWIFT**

```
import Social

let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
vc.add(imageView.image!)
vc.add(URL(string: "http://www.example.com/"))
vc.setInitialText("Initial text here.")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

More Details [Facebook and twitter sharing](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/)

Comment: I want to share product details automatically in fb when the user press share button...i don't want user to put anything manually..Thanks

Comment: @NeerajSonaro Please updated your question with full details.

Comment: @HarshalValanda, the above code is good enough. Just embed the above code in the IBAction of your share method.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fzwxft

This is my products details page...When the user press FB Share button...i want to post details about the product automatically in his timeline.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro you can sharing via graph api. i am not sure in object c but i can update my answer with swift

Comment: @Harshal Valanda I am getting this when i am using your code for objective-c
[core] SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType com.apple.social.facebook returning 0

Comment: Check in you setting there is no Facebook account inserted. Need to insert a fb account in setting

Comment: go to settings -> Facebook and add your credentials.

Comment: Done..Thanks Bro :)

Comment: If you want directly post to Facebook please check facebook graph api. @NeerajSonaro Welcome

Answer (score 1):

Use SLComposeViewController to display native dialog box & post your content on Facebook.

```
 if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    __weak CFShareToFacebookViewController *weakSelf = self;

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:self.captionTextField.text];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
        [controller addImage:self.selectedImage];
        [controller setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

          switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
              break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone: {

            }
              break;

            default:
              break;
          }
        }];

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

  }
```

Comment: I want to share product details automatically in fb when the user press share button...i dont want user to put anything manually..Thanks.

Comment: Use Graph API to post your content without any dialog presented to user

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/post][1]